# Efficient way to match two IDs from two very long containers

Tags: java, string, algorithm, list

I have two very huge lists of String, one containing some IDs(over 70k) and another list containing some String messages, each line containing an ID(over 400k entries). I need that for each ID from first list to get all the messages with the same ID from the second list. I tried  by creating some Threads that for each ID from first list, iterates the entire second list and  retrieve&remove the message. This seems to create too many Iterator objects, resulting in OOM in not enough memory is given. Also, CPU is 100% when iterating the second list. Any suggestions? I can change the implementation, also the containers were I keep the messages.

Thanks.

```
while (condition) {                    
    <Message> iterator = msgQueue.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Message message = iterator.next();

                    if (filter.filter(message)) {
                        iterator.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Transform your second list into a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` (the key being the ID, and the value being a list of messages containing this ID). Then iterate through your first list and get the corresponding messages from the map.

You could use one of Guava's [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put those objects not into two list like you did, but in Map, where the key is the Id from the first list, and the values is the Set of messages containing Id.

Answer (score 0):

A less threading algorithm can do. Sorting both lists by ID and taking a range of IDs (list of lists?) to iterate will be faster and hence feasible for sequential processing or less threads.